# Painting with weird noise

Tags: texture-painting, noise-reduction

I'm new regarding painting a model in Blender, I had some difficult with making a texture to paint, but when I did that, while painting this weird noise appears and I can't seem to find the solution.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the **Jitter** value set to 0.000 in a *Stroke panel*? I guess it may solve the problem.

Comment: Yes it's set to 0, should I change it? It seems to do nothing.
I noticed now, that beneath the bottom lip he paints it well, but the rest of the model it gets all "bananas". 

Could it possibly be something involved with smoothing the model?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a texture or a brush mask texture? That could be what is happening, but can't see the rest of your settings for the brush.